# Sending command line arguments from client to server

Tags: c, sockets

I want to input arguments from the command line to the client and make the server receive them and print them.

current codes:

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PORT 8080 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int sock = 0, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)  
    { 
        printf(Invalid address\n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    { 
        printf("Connection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
     if(argc>=2){
 int i, numb;
 for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    send(sock , &argv[i] , 10000 , 0 ); 
}
}
    return 0; 
}
```

Server:

```
#define PORT 8080 
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR , &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
      valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
      puts("The client sent the values: ");

       if(argc>=2){
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
      int* valuerec=(int *)buffer;
      int val2=*valuerec;
      printf("%d\n", val2); 
      puts(" ");
}
}
    return 0; 
}
```

I tried doing it multiple ways such as using `atoi` before sending but all resulted in no output of numbers, any help on how I can establish this?
I am aware I didn't include the server libraries in this post but that is just to make it shorter.

Comment: I suggest you use tools like `socat` (Linux) or Herkules (Windows) to act as client/server so you can better debug the client/server components of your work separately.

Comment: I see a few problems here. You are using `send()` on a TCP socket, which means it's the same as calling `write()` because TCP has no notion of message boundaries. Then you try to send 10000 bytes when you should probably be sending just the number of bytes in each argument, plus a delimiter. On the receiving end you need to check for the delimiter and parse the arguments.

Comment: @HellmarBecker okay so first the 10000 bytes was just put because I was trying multiple things (sending it as an int and other such so instead of saying `sizeof(int)` then changing I just put 10000), what else can I use other than `send()`?

Comment: @ayrebelcoding I would just use `write( sock, argv[i], 1 + strlen( argv[i] ))`. That way you write the entire string, including the terminating `\0` that you can conveniently use as a delimiter.

Comment: @ayrebelcoding In real life, check the return value because `write()` does not guarantee that all bytes are written, and `errno` if the return value is -1.

Comment: @HellmarBecker I just replaced `send` with this `write` without changing anything in the server side (same casting and everything) and still got no output of numbers.

Comment: ...and then you need to loop the recv() until you find the delimiter.  'valread', assuming >0, is the ONLY way to know how many bytes have been loaded into the buffer - it could be 1 for every recv call, and your code MUST handle that edge case.

Comment: I used `read()` not `revc()`, how will this affect my code?

Comment: No matter if you use `read()` or `recv()`, @MartinJames 's remark holds true. Basically you loop your `read()` calls until you hit EOF, then parse the result.

Comment: I used this https://imgur.com/a/zySToFA and got an error in writing from the client side, might have understood what you guys meant in a wrong way.